# SSIS how to automatically map a newly added source column into all subsequent transformations and destinations

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have this ETL project in SSIS that collects some data in a Firebird database, makes some transformations, and insert them into a dimensional model in a SQL Server database.
I had to make a change in the model adding some columns and had to map them manually in all components from source throughout the project.
My question is: is there any way to automatically map newly added columns without having to check them manually in all subsequent transformation components?

Thanks,

Comment: None that I know of - and it makes sense. Any newly added column could be of any data type, used for anything. There is no guarantee that a given new column will be needed, and no guarantee that a newly added column will be used for anything more than a conditional check in the first step. It needs to be added everywhere manually because that is what informs the package that it is needed in each of these subsequent steps.

Comment: i have done this before using code generation. The approach I took was to read a tables column information using SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) and then generate packages to extract, transform, and load data. It took a good bit of preparation to write the code generator but It made sense when developing packages for hundreds of tables.

Comment: You could do this using code generation, however this would only be efficient if you have to do this hundreds of times.

Answer (score 1):

We use BIML along with some metadata that we store in a database to generate our SSIS packages.  If a new source attribute is introduced, we simply add that attribute to our metadata and regenerate the packages. The benefit with this approach is that you can regeneration multiple packages in one go.

Generating SSIS packages using BIML does rely on your solution using very strict, reusable patterns.

Marius